# logstash: Input File plugin, reading order

Tags: logstash

I got a problem fo reading some logs files. actually this logs files are generating by log4j and when the logs file exceeds 5MB the title of this one is transform "service.Log20170524" to "service.log20170524.1"

so, at the end of the day we got this :

[screen capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7H0Zd.png)

as you can see the first log file generated is "Service.Log20170524.2" and the last one is "Service.Log20170524". my problem is that : my report is not good because of Logstash start reading all this files by the last one ("Service.Log20170524")

Do you have any solutions, to read all this file, by creation date ?

Comment: If you are using log4j, the logs should contain timestamps. Extract the timestamp, parse it and put it in the field `@timestamp`. Then you'll be able to order your report by date (I suppose in elasticsearch).

Comment: the things is, I want to aggregate my logs before sending them to a central server. the logs that i'm parsing are aplicative log, about task execution. Each task has a begining and an end. between the begining and the end i'm recording all error comming. and sometimes the end is not in the same log file.
and the problem i got, is that sometime the end come before the begining of the task execution

Comment: With these requirements, I don't think that logstash is the right tool, maybe you should write a dedicated java program to parse the files. Or you should run logstash continuously so that the task are gathered as they are written to the files (logstash is able to deal with file rotation, see https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-file.html#_file_rotation_2)